# Filter all rows based on one specific index value, python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to output a filtered list based on the input of the index.
In my case, I want to make the Location the index, and only show all the results whose location is 'Switzerland'. I am using jupyter-notebook

I have an xlsx file called Book1 containing [here.][1]
, I type this in.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
from scipy import stats

substats=pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', index_col=1) #index_col=1 makes Location the index
```

I am stuck, but I am expecting [the output to be like this][2]

Notice that the second image index is not 4, 6, but instead 1, 2.

Can you help me with this?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIbKx.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/whSEP.png

Comment: welcome to SO. Can you provide more info about the error that you're encountering? A copy paste of the error trace from the console will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an off-by-one error

You are assuming `Pandas` is 0-indexing their arrays, but it looks like they are 1-indexing it.

Using the 2nd column as the index should solve this.

Comment: I need the Location to be the index. if i use index_col=2, Rank would be the index, not the location. And I want to output all the institutions whose LOCATION is in Switzerland.